# HTML5 video не работает в Safari

Tags: html, html5, видео, safari

Видео на странице работает в Chrome, Firefox но не работает в Safari

```
<video controls muted preload="none" playsinline src="/path/to/video" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Кодеки

video h.264/mpeg-4 avc

audio mpeg aac audio mp4a

Показывает такую картинку

[image: l]

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Тег не закрыт, [он же не одинарный](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video)

Comment: Тег закрыт. Решил проблему https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53952944/html5-video-problems-on-safari

Comment: Значит вы сюда код добавили неверный. Уж сорри, что в глаза слету бросилось :) Решили проблему это отлично. Спасибо, за то что поделились решением.